# Regular Expression with logical AND NOT functionality

Tags: c#, regex

I'd like to match all strings (not words) that contain `cat` or `dog` but not those that contain `catdog`.

Basically the string logic equivilent of:

```
string s;
(s.contains('cat') || s.contains('dog')) && !s.contains('catdog')
```

#### Test Values:

```
cat
dog
catdog
catsAreSoft
IHavedogs
```

#### Regular expression (doesn't actually work):

```
(cat)|(dog)|^(?!catdog)
```

#### Matched Values

```
cat
dog
catsAreSoft
IHavedogs
```

Comment: You can use `(?<=\s|^)(?:cat|dog)(?=\s|$)`

Comment: _"all strings that contain"_ What about "**cat**egory" ? Match? Or do you mean cat or dog as a whole word, only. Not part of a word?

Comment: Wow everyone goes crazy for regex questions, 6 answers and 19 views

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I think you wrongly marked this as being a duplicate. Just because almost every answer focused on answering "You need to search for whole words" doesn't mean that this was asked for. In fact: The Original post explicitly asked for "strings (not words) containing…".

Comment: @Skeeve The question got edited. I changed the close reason, this question is still a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All answers were focussing on "cat" and "dog" being a single word.

The question was

> all **strings that contain** 'cat' or 'dog'

So I think a solution should be:

```
$ perl -ne 'print if /cat(?!dog)|(?<!cat)dog/' << HERE
> cat
> dog
> catdog
> hasdogcat
> hascatdog
> has just cat dog
> HERE
cat
dog
hasdogcat
has just cat dog
```

Comment: P.S. Explanation: `cat(?!dog)` means "cat" not followed by "doc". `(?>!cat)dog` means "dog" not preceeded by "cat".

Answer (score 4):

Just search using this alternation:

```
\b(?:cat|dog)\b
```

This will match literal `cat` or `dog`, but only as standalone words.

Answer (score 1):

Just use *word boundaries* `\b`

> Matches at a position that is followed by a word character but not
>   preceded by a word character, or that is preceded by a word character
>   but not followed by a word character.

```
\bcat\b|\bdog\b
```

Answer (score 1):

Your original expression seems to be fine, we would be only using word boundary here:

```
(\bcat\b|\bdog\b)
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/acM2U5/1/)

and if we wish to find strings that would contain cat and dog, we would be expanding it to:

```
(?=.*\bcat\b|.*\bdog\b).*
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/IigP1f/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Test 1

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(\bcat\b|\bdog\b)";
        string input = @"cat
dog
catdog";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Test 2

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(?=.*\bcat\b|.*\bdog\b).*";
        string input = @"cat
dog
catdog
Anything we wish before cat then anything we wish afterwards
Anything we wish before dog then anything we wish afterwards
Anything we wish before catdog then anything we wish afterwards";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Match string `cat` or `dog` only if they are surrounded by `space` or `end` or `start` of string

You can use

```
(?<=\s|^)(?:cat|dog)(?=\s|$)
```

- `(?<=\s|^)` - Match must be preceded by `space` or `start of string`
- `(?:cat|dog)` - Match `cat` or `dog`
- `(?=\s|$)` - Match must be followed by `space` or `end of string`

***P.S. :-*** This will take care of string such `cat'dog` or `cat-dog` whereas using `\b` will not

Answer (score 0):

You could try this expression: `(?(?=cat)(?!catdog)cat)|(?(?=dog)(?<!cat)dog)`

Logic explanation:

`(?(?=cat)(?!catdog)cat)` - assert that what follows is `cat`, but if it is, then assert then what follows is NOT `catdog`, if those are true, match `cat`

`(?(?=dog)(?<!cat)dog)` - assert that what follows is `dog`, if it does, then assert then what is preceding is NOT `cat`, if those are true, then match `dog`.

Whole expression is just alternation between those two.

It allows you to match any `cat` and `dog` if it isn;t part of the `catdgog`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EzHeAX/1)